# Compile Error in Objective-C iPhone Game

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, lua

I am making a game in Cocos 2D and Kobold 2D, and when I opened up Xcode today, I got this weird OSACompile Error.

```
OSACompile Projectfiles/Resources/config.lua
    cd /Users/shalinvs/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.1.0/targeted
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/osacompile -l AppleScript -d -o /Users/shalinvs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-fpbpczqvlbltxpalqzlddxzetvpq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/targeted-iOS.app/config.scpt Projectfiles/Resources/config.lua

Projectfiles/Resources/config.lua:2: error: Expected end of line, etc. but found “*”. (-2741)
Command /usr/bin/osacompile failed with exit code 1
```

This is my config file:

```
--[[
* Kobold2D™ --- http://www.kobold2d.org
* Copyright (c) 2010-2011 Steffen Itterheim.
* Released under MIT License in Germany (LICENSE-Kobold2D.txt).
--]]


--[[
* Need help with the KKStartupConfig settings?
* ------ http://www.kobold2d.com/x/ygMO ------
--]]


local config =
{
KKStartupConfig =
{
-- load first scene from a class with this name, or from a Lua script with this name with .lua appended
FirstSceneClassName = "Title",

MaxFrameRate = 60,
DisplayFPS = YES,

EnableUserInteraction = YES,
EnableMultiTouch = NO,

-- Render settings
DefaultTexturePixelFormat = TexturePixelFormat.RGBA8888,
GLViewColorFormat = GLViewColorFormat.RGB565,
GLViewDepthFormat = GLViewDepthFormat.DepthNone,
GLViewMultiSampling = NO,
GLViewNumberOfSamples = 0,

Enable2DProjection = NO,
EnableRetinaDisplaySupport = YES,
EnableGLViewNodeHitTesting = NO,
EnableStatusBar = NO,

-- Orientation & Autorotation
-- Kobold2D uses the supported orientations from the Target's Summary pane: http://cl.ly/2l132Z2f463H2O3r0M1O
-- (same as Info.plist key UISupportedInterfaceOrientations aka "Supported interface orientations")

-- iAd setup
EnableAdBanner = YES,
PlaceBannerOnBottom = NO,
LoadOnlyPortraitBanners = NO,
LoadOnlyLandscapeBanners = NO,
AdProviders = "iAd, AdMob", -- comma seperated list -> "iAd, AdMob" means: use iAd if available, otherwise AdMob
AdMobRefreshRate = 15,
AdMobFirstAdDelay = 5,
AdMobPublisherID = "YOUR_ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID", -- how to get an AdMob Publisher ID: http://developer.admob.com/wiki/PublisherSetup
AdMobTestMode = YES,

-- Mac OS specific settings
AutoScale = NO,
AcceptsMouseMovedEvents = NO,
EnableFullScreen = NO,
},

-- you can create your own config sections using the same mechanism and use KKConfig to access the parameters
-- or use the KKConfig injectPropertiesFromKeyPath method
HelloWorldSettings =
{
HelloWorldString = "Hello Kobold2D!",
HelloWorldFontName = "Marker Felt",
HelloWorldFontSize = 50,
},
}

return config
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Is there anything that I can do to fix this? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode apparently wants to compile the Lua script as AppleScript. In Kobold2D the lua file type is set to "Applescript preconpiled" for better syntax highlighting. If you set the filetype to " Applescript source" then that might be the cause.

Check that the lua file is only in the copy bundle resources Build Phase and not under compile sources. Also under Build Rules there should be no rule for .lua files. And verify the lua file type.